# Why is this error occuring when i try to make a display

Tags: java, lwjgl

I was trying to make a display using lwjgl and i got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Unsafe
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtilSun$AccessorUnsafe.getUnsafeInstance(MemoryUtilSun.java:74)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtilSun$AccessorUnsafe.<init>(MemoryUtilSun.java:62)
    at 

java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:304)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:685)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtil.loadAccessor(MemoryUtil.java:375)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:63)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.setTitle(WindowsDisplay.java:523)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.setTitle(Display.java:541)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:312)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:797)
    at The_Last_Survivor/com.tls.engines.Render.display.create(display.java:26)
    at The_Last_Survivor/com.tls.engines.Start.Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Unsafe
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 16 more
```

This is the program i wrote:

```
package com.tls.engines.Render;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;

public class display
{
    private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 720;
    private static final int FPS_cap = 30; // TO-DO: Make a settings menu that changes this and remove final
    
    public static void create()
    {
        
        ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2);
        attribs.withForwardCompatible(true);
        attribs.withProfileCore(true);
        
        try
        {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
        }
        catch (LWJGLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
    }
    
    public static void update()
    {
        Display.sync(FPS_cap);
        display.update();
    }
    
    public static void close()
    {
        Display.destroy();
    }
    
}
```

I have imported the jinput, lwjgl_test, lwjgl_util, lwjgl, and slick-util jar files and using lwjgl 2, I was having problems with lwjgl_debug right before this but i managed to fix it by simply removing and deleting it from my library

Here is where i call the function:

```
package com.tls.engines.Start;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import com.tls.engines.Render.display;

public class Starter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        display.create();
        
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            //TO-DO: Make game logic
            //TO-DO: Make renderer
            display.update();
        }
        
        display.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java Class names are written uppercase. Like "Display" and not "display". Also please provide more code, especially there, where you call this class or anything from this class. Also provide the main method please.

Comment: I called the function from the main method, I have edited the original post to show the code

Comment: Which version of LWJGL are you using, with which version of Java?

Comment: LWJGL 2.9.1 and Java 20

Comment: LWJGL 2 has not been in development since 2015 or so. Java's internals have changed since then. Try using LWJGL 3 instead.

Comment: alright got it!